# In a React App, are only imported functions counted towards the size / overhead of the APP for the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, web-deployment

For example, my React APP depends on `MUI` package.

But I only import the `Slider` and `AutoComplete` from the package.

Will only these 2 components have an effect on my APP in terms of performance to the end user? Or does the entire package have the same effect regardless just because it is a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack (shipped with `create-react-app`) makes sure that imports like that are transformed in production to minimise bundle size.

However, this is **not** the case in development. Without custom babel config, you will import the entire library and your app will take forever to start in development mode. The Mui docs [has a section](https://mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2) on how to deal with that, but it's a little outdated wrt/ `create-react-app`. Nowadays [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) exists that makes this whole process a lot easier. But if you can't be bothered to learn *yet another CRA anti-eject library*, you can follow Mui's tutorial and get the exact same result, just less future-proof.